# How to create a set of tables from a table containing a nested json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a big table containing a json column, itself containing deep nested lists.

So far we've been extracting the properties we needed from the json by name, but I would really like to "explode" this json column automatically into as many tables as necessary, so we would get :

- A table similar to the source table, same number of rows, containing the non json columns and the flattened unnested properties of the json.
- nested elements in as many tables as necessary, linked to their parent elements by the relevant id.

I believe (am I wrong ?) a general approach is possible from any table containing a single nested json column as long as it is structured consistently, and it looks to me like a common enough problem that might have been solved in an efficient way already.

I have found posts such as this one discussing this issue in python, but I cannot store everything in RAM:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d

- My input is a table, and the name of its column containing json strings.
- My desired output is a set of jsonless tables containing all the information formerly contained in the json column of my source table.

Any pointer how I could do this ?

Comment: would partitioning be of any help to you, basically use JSONB instead of JSON datatype and then it can be partitioned for the range of that column.

Comment: Raj I've hopefully clarified my desired output a bit, I don't think partitioning helps,as far as I understand it wouldn't affect the structure of my data.

Comment: It is possible, but you would have to write some PL functions to achieve it. The question would be, the tables are temporal? if not, I recommend to the design of the new structures first, then, write the PL or PLs. Also, I would not recommend for it to be automatic unless everything is under control, cause a process like this takes a lot of resources depending on the amount of data. Also, if there is a lot of data, using triggers would be advisable.